# Odoo configuration with Pycharm on Windows 10

Tags: pycharm, windows-10, odoo, odoo-13

Please i need to know when i configure odoo with pycharm community version, i use odoo installed package of course after installation the exe file or the source package downloaded from git and what is the difference.

Comment: Any answers, please?

Answer (score 0):

1. First download odoo source from github
2. Download python and PostgreSQL database
3. Set environment variable for python and postgreSQL
4. Configure Pycharm with odoo

I am not going to share link here...coz moderator not allowed to share link